# Zend Debugger Terminates After Index Page

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-debugger

I have a website running using Zend Framework and am trying to setup Zend Debugger.  Zend Debugger is installed and it works correctly with the tutorial PHP pages however when I try debugging with my app, it will work for the index page but then the debugger will terminate.

I am running Apache2.2 with PHP 5.3.

I have a virtual host setup - dev.mysite.com that points to index.php so I'm not using http://localhost/mysite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had just installed Apache 2 on Ubuntu and it turns out that mod_rewrite is not enabled by default.  I needed to do "sudo a2enmod rewrite" and now the debugger seems to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sticky note in the Zend Forum dealing with [Setting Up Zend Debugger](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=962).

If the information in the article won't help, try to be more specific about your setup. My guess is you're missing `dummy.php` in your ZF project, but there is really not enough information about your setup in the question to say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with this as well, my issues came down to one gotcha and one less obvious thing

the gotcha was the eclipse browser setting was set to use internal browse, 'default system browser' which happened to be chrome.  This meant that it would launch chrome but connect to the internal browser.  that started working when configered for external browser and explicitly chrome rather than default system browser.  Window | Preferences | General for web browser settings

The second issue was around symbolic links.  I used symbolic links to link source from a repo into the framework hierarchy.  This meant the eclipse project explorer saw one file (the symbolic path) and the debugger saw another (the 'rela' path inside the repo).  So breakpoints set in the php explorer version of the file were not seen by the debugger. I solved this by checking out the repo beside the framework directory, symlinking my repo folders into the framework as before but using eclipse 'exclude from build path' on the symlinks so that both php explorer and debugger saw the real path to the file